# How can I make ListView CrossAxisAlignment wrap content?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My goal is to make a horizontally scrolling ListView. I would like the height to be the same as the height of the largest item inside the ListView. Right now, the horizontal ListView expands to fill the entire vertical screen. How can I shrink the height without specifying a height and still be able to scroll?

Here is a dartpad link with the code that I have: https://dartpad.dev/13bd819a46e6c2d840147a5855a6e54c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will be your desired output, try this,

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var fraction = OutlinedContainer(
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("100"),
                Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Text("300"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));

    return Scaffold(
        body: OutlinedContainer(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            fraction,fraction,   fraction
          ],),]),
        ));
  }
}

class OutlinedContainer extends Container {
  OutlinedContainer({@required Widget child}) : super(child: child,             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 3),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)));
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can accept this answer if correct Because other user follow Approved answer so it will be easy for them